# Error creating SolidColorBrush

Tags: c++, direct2d

In my code I am trying to create a Direct2D SolidColorBrush like so

```
ID2D1SolidColorBrush *pBgBrush;
D2D1::ColorF color = D2D1::ColorF(0x9ACD32, 1.0f);
pRenderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(color, &pBgBrush);
```

When the `CreateSolidColorBrush` function is called an error is thrown inside the `d2d1.h` header file which is

```
First-chance exception at 0x012519C0 in 2012_10_22__WICBitmapRenderTargetExploration.exe:
0xC0000005: 
Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

What is causing this? How do I fix it?

Comment: Pardon my stupid question: pRenderTarget is, or is not NULL?

Comment: Thanks Craig, It does appear to be NULL. I don't know why. C++ is very new to me this is only my second C++ console app I'm not quite to grips with it yet.

Comment: It no-doubt came from an API that returned it as an out-param. Check the HRESULT of that API and see if you can find out why it failed.

Comment: Quick check and it looks like your call to `CreateHwndRenderTarget` is likely the failure point (if not the outright factory). or `CreateHwndRenderTarget` is never called before your code above is. I'd look there first.

Comment: Thanks Craig! I think I have it. I'm using `CreateWicBitmapRenderTarget` and it seems that the bitmap I was supplying had an invalid pixel format. Thanks for spurring me on.

Comment: Very glad you found the problem. I don't program D2D at all, but its like all the other API-rooted Microsoft COM libraries. Just takes some getting used to. You may want to look and see if they have a _com_util smart-pointer layer for D2D. I would be shocked if they don't, and it makes managing all the COM resources *much* easier for you (think of it as MS's smart-pointers for COM). if not, ATL::CComPtr<> will do if you decide to drink the smart-pointer kool-aid.